# EF Core - Multiple owned types mapping issue

Tags: entity-framework-core

I wanted to ask about building the model in EntityFramework Core - v 2.1.
First things first - what I want to achieve is described below:

```cs
//  I want this entity to be stored in database, with EntityReferences as owned records, 
//  stored within the same table.
//  There will be more properties of type EntityReference.
public partial class CdiEmailEvent
{
    public override Guid Id { get; set; }
    public EntityReference CdiAccountId
    public EntityReference CdiAutomationId
}

//  EntityReference is a pointer to record, containing Id of target record and it's type.
//  So Id does not point to CdiEmailEntity record, but for example an Account or Contact.
//  I want this to be an owned record within CdiEmailEvent.
public sealed class EntityReference : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string LogicalName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

So the real data could look like:

```cs
new CdiEmailEvent {
    Id = "18640407-1A44-430A-8267-96BD23CC9EE8",

    CdiAccountId = new CdiAccountId {
        Id = "FBBB4932-C74C-47CE-8D1B-909C5975D945",
        Name = "Account",
        LogicalName = "cdi_account"
    },

    CdiAutomationId = new CdiAccountId {
        Id = "5496BC1C-C5FD-4AFB-B6D9-913DD5549C13",
        Name = "Automation",
        LogicalName = "cdi_automation"
    },

    ...
}
```

And I'd like databese table to look like:

```
Id                                      |   CdiAccountId                            |   CdiAccountName  |   CdiAccountLogicalName   |   CdiAutomationId                         |   CdiAutomationName   |   CdiAutomationLogicalName
"18640407-1A44-430A-8267-96BD23CC9EE8"  |   "FBBB4932-C74C-47CE-8D1B-909C5975D945"  |   "Account"       |   "cdi_account"           |   "5496BC1C-C5FD-4AFB-B6D9-913DD5549C13"  |   Automation          |   "cdi_automation"
```

My current model configuration is:

```cs
modelBuilder
    .Entity<CdiEmailEvent>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.CdiEmailEventId);

        entity.OwnsOne(rel => rel.CdiAccountId);
        entity.OwnsOne(rel => rel.CdiAutomationId);

        ...

        entity.ToTable("CdiEmailEvents", this._databaseConfig.DatabaseSchema);
    });
```

The issue that I'm encountering is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity of type 'CdiEmailEvent' is sharing
 the table 'replication.CdiEmailEvents' with entities of type 
'CdiEmailEvent.CdiAutomationId#EntityReference', but there is no entity of this
 type with the same key value '{CdiEmailEventId: 8a99d6ab-cd82-4eb8-b548-50d903d6f26c}' 
that has been marked as 'Added'.'
```

I guess that EF Core is trying to use CdiAutomationId as a reference to CdiEmailEvent. Does anyone know how can I alter such behavior, and enforce EF Core to treat CdiAutomationId simply as an object without any keys? I went through EF Core's documentation, but it's not very descriptive in this matter.

Comment: It doesn't sound like mapping problem to me, but usage issue. What operation is producing the error? Can you provide a small code snippet that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Ivan, from what I see by looking at table generation script, it doesn't perceive Id on CdiAccountId as a value, but as a key. It fails on SaveChanges().

'CREATE TABLE [replication].[CdiEmailEvents] (
    [LogicalName] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [EntityState] int NULL,
    [RowVersion] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [CdiEmailEventId] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [CdiAccountId_LogicalName] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [CdiAccountId_Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [CdiAccountId_RowVersion] nvarchar(max) NULL...'

Comment: I can't reproduce. Actually `entity.HasKey(e => e.CdiEmailEventId);` does not compile with the provided model. Which makes me think the problem is with some base class having the `Id` property you are overriding plus additional `CdiEmailEventId` property not shown there and configured as PK.